# How to convert Lucene query to Mongo understanding form

Tags: mongodb, lucene

For Example Lucene query is `(euid:3) AND (sev:0)` but this is not understandable by Mongo.

Is it possible to convert Lucene query to Mongo understanding form ?

Comment: Using the `CLI` your query would look like `db.collection.find({euid:3, sev:0})`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for this in MongoDB would be:

```
   db.collectionName.find( { "euid" : 2, "sev" : 0 } );
```

Comma separated conditions are treated as an "AND" so the above syntax says find me document in collection where euid is equal to 2 and sev is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene includes a query parser that makes it relatively straight forward to convert lucene queries into Mongo queries.

You have to take care with mongo search terms are typed ("1.0" != 1.0F) and you might not get the results you expect.

For an example query converter, take a look at the MongoQueryConverter that's included with the scaleset-search API.  If there is interest, I can release this as a standalone library which can be used with or without Jongo.

https://github.com/scaleset/scaleset-search/blob/master/src/main/java/com/scaleset/search/mongo/MongoQueryConverter.java

Comment: I would be very interested in having this released as a standalone library. I use spring-data-mongodb and would like to have users supply queries in lucene. Thanks!